# GET authorization header bearer automatically with python

Tags: python, api, bearer-token, http-authentication

I would like to get the header authentication bearer with python. I have run the code below, but I have an empty return (Response [500], Response [200]).

Can you give me some guidelines to identify the problem and find a solution

**1.**

```
import requests

headers = {
    'authority': 'desk-api.nomination.fr',
    'pragma': 'no-cache',
    'cache-control': 'no-cache',
    'sec-ch-ua': '" Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="90", "Google Chrome";v="90"',
    'accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.85 Safari/537.36',
    'content-type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
    'origin': 'https://app.nomination.fr',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'same-site',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
    'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
    'referer': 'https://app.nomination.fr/',
    'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
}

data = '{"login":"xxxxx","password":""}'

response = requests.post('https://desk-api.nomination.fr/v1/authentication/auth/local', headers=headers, data=data)
```

**2.**

```
import requests
username ="xxxx",
password = "ppp",
url = "https://app.xxxx.fr/login?fromState=app.home/"
with requests.session() as session:
    reponse  = session.post(url, auth = (username,password))
```

Comment: Data should be dictionary. Test it.

Comment: Thank you,

I have this message : <Response [500]>

Comment: Are you sure that that's how api wants to get the login and pass?, could you add link to some api documentation?

Comment: My goal is to recurve the authentication token for the connexion on the site 'https://app.nxxxxx.fr/'. I already have the login and the password.